# Си: проверить директорию - пуста ли она

Tags: c, linux, macos

Как проверить директорию - пуста ли она?

Comment: Укажите операционную систему.

Comment: Linux, желательно и MacOs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ - открыть каталог opendir'ом и посчитать количество файлов/папок в нем. На самом деле даже делать подсчет не нужно - если хоть один файл есть - не пустая. Будет работать под линуксом и макосью. Для примера, можно на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554120/open-directory-using-c) посмотреть.

Answer (score 4):

Например, так (проверки на корректность аргументов и opendir() опущены):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DIR * dir;
    struct dirent * dirent;
    int files_found = 0;

    dir = opendir( argv[1] );
    while( dirent = readdir(dir) )
    {
        if( strcmp(dirent->d_name, ".") || strcmp(dirent->d_name, "..") )
        {
            files_found = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    closedir( dir );

    printf( "Directory \"%s\" is%s empty\n", argv[1], files_found ? " NOT" : "" );
    return files_found;
}
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, к заголовочным файлам `string.h`, чтобы компилятор на `strcmp` не ругался.

Comment: Странно, gcc (4.8.2) без -Wall не ругается, а я и не заметил... Поправил.

Comment: А, понял. На `c` или `C` он и не должен ругаться, а вот если файл `cpp`, `cxx` или `c++` :-)

Answer (score 1):

В заголовочном файле `dirent.h` объявлены функции, позволяющие получать информацию о директориях: `opendir` и `readdir`.

Функция `opendir` принимает путь к директории и возвращает указатель на список с информацией о содержимом директории, который можно последовательно перебирать с помощью команды `readdir`. Когда список заканчивается, `readdir` возвращает `NULL`. Даже в пустой директории есть поддиректории `.` и `..`. Если в директории только они, то она пуста.

Comment: "Если же директория пуста, то она вернёт NULL сразу." - нет, ибо "." и ".."

Comment: Да, вы правы. Исправил.